# SpecFlow.NUnit via Nuget: Missing reference to nunit.core

Tags: nunit, nuget, specflow

I just installed the 'specflow.nunit' package via nuget, but the project containing the specs want compile anymore, because of the `SpecFlowNUnitExtension` class that is added to the project is missing references to nunit.core (more specifically the 'NUnit.Core' and 'NUnit.Core.Extensibility' namespaces can't be found). Anyone else had the same issue? Have you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I fixed it by installing the NUnitTestAdapter Nuget package.

Comment: Same, I believe this is the better answer

Comment: Set also "Copy Local" property of nunit.core.interfaces assembly to True.

Comment: @Morten. This is master piece. I was spending 1 hour to figure the problem. Your answer helped me today. 2 upvotes :)

Comment: In VS 2017, you have to do this, then manually go add the references under {SolutionDir}/packages/NUnitTestAdapter.2.1.1/tools/.

Answer (score 4):

Okei, seems I found away to solve it; The dll's needed can be downloaded from http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download. Download the 'bin'-version, extract the zip archive, and inside the folder 'lib' there are 2 assemblies that's needed by SpecFlowNUnitExtension:
- nunit.core.dll
- nunit.core.interfaces.dll

Add a references to these two dll's and project compiles.

(a bit awkward though; shouldn't these assemblies be bundled with the specflow.nunit package?)

Answer (score 1):

Our fix was to delete SpecFlowNUnitExtension.cs from our project that was added during the install of the SpecFlow.NUnit NuGet package.  According to the comments in the top of the file, it is only needed if you are using one of the nunit.console runners which we are not using.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this is still an issue, but I had the same problem today. I'm probably doing something wrong.... :)

After much searching and installing and reinstalling, I found this post:
https://answers.launchpad.net/nunitv2/+question/192677

I installed the deprecated NUnit.Runners package which finally made the reference errors go away. This seems really kludgey, so again, I must be missing something, but I thought it would be helpful to document here in case someone else runs into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the NUnitV2.Core Nuget package resolved the missing reference errors.